# Django PUT TestCase fails if client initialised in setUpTestData() but passes if client initialized in setUp()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, tdd, django-testing

I am writing tests where every test case passes except the PUT

```
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


class ViewTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.client = APIClient()

    def setUp(self):
        """setUp() runs before every single test method."""
        self.user_data = {'first_name': "John", 'last_name': "Doe", 'email_id': "john@doe.com",
                          'phone_number': "987654321", 'is_verified': False}
        self.response = self.client.post(
            reverse('create'),
            self.user_data,
            format='json')

    def test_api_can_update_user(self):
        user = User.objects.get()
        changes = {'first_name': "Johnny"}
        changed_user_data = {**self.user_data, **changes}

        response = self.client.put(
            reverse('details', kwargs={'email': user.email_id}),
            changed_user_data,
            format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This test case fails with response.status_code = 415 (unsupported media type)
whereas if I just move the client initialization from setUpTestData() to setUp()
everything passes.

```
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()   # Test case passed now.
        ...
```

There are other tests for GET, POST, DELETE all of which pass
irrespective of whether client instance is shared(setUpTestData) or not.

PS: All apis including PUT work from DRF web api view.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding and with your test above `client` is not an instance attribute of the class instead it is a class attribute so hence the error response. Try changing `self.client` to `cls.client` in your `setUp` method and `test_api_can_update_user` method. 
Also in my experience it is advisable to initialise `client` before creating the testcases.

Answer (score 0):

using APITestCase instead of TestCase helpled.
APITestCase initializes self.client = APIClient() for you
In this case you dont need to initialize cls.client.

```
class ViewTestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """setUp() runs before every single test method."""
    ....
```